# Nginx redirect domain.com/blog/posts to sub.domain.com/blog/posts

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain, blogs

Yet another nginx redirect question.

I've been trying to redirect `domain.com/blog/post-1`, `/blog/post-2` to `sub.domain.com/blog/post-1`, etc.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to serve anything on domain.com without subdomains, add this block:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://sub.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

If you want to use it somehow, add this to your domain.com server block:

```
location /blog {
    rewrite     ^ http://sub.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Of course, in any case you want sub.domain.com server block which is catching this request.

Comment: Please mark my answer as right one so question will not be marked as "unanswered" anymore. I'm glad that helped you:)

Comment: I have. Wish I could up vote, as soon as I get a few, I will. Thank you again.